# Carousel card not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

Carousel not working please provide me guidelines to make it run.I tried but JavaScript is not working. Kindly provide me actual guidance to make it run.https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/YzeRRrm. Have a glance at what i made,only problem i'm facing is with javascript, i shall be highly obliged if you can solve this.

```js
let currentScrollPosition = 0;
let scrollAmount = 320;

        const sCont = document.querySelector(".card-container");
        const hScroll = document.querySelector(".horizontal-scroll");

        let maxScroll = -(sCont.offsetWidth + hScroll.offsetWidth);


        function scrollHorizontally(val){
            currentScrollPosition += (val * scrollAmount);

        if (currentScrollPosition > 0) {
                currentScrollPosition = 0
        }
        
        if (currentScrollPosition < maxScroll) {
                currentScrollPosition = maxscroll;
        }

            sCont.style.left = currentScrollPosition + "px";
        }
```

```css
.horizontal-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: 30%;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    margin-left: 50px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    gap: 10px;
}
.card-container .card{
    min-width: 280px;
    flex: 1;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
  background: #00F260;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0575E6, #00F260); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align:center;
}
.card-container .card img{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    pointer-events: none;       
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display:block;
    object-fit: fill;
    height: 180px;
    }
/* btn */
.horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll{
    background: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #007bff;
    transition:  all .2s linear;
    }
.horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.horizontal-scroll .btn-scroll:focus{
    outline: none;
    background-color:#007bff;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-left{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(200px/2);
}
.horizontal-scroll #btn-scroll-right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(200px/2);
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
        <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-left" onclick="scrollHorizontally(1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn-scroll" id="btn-scroll-right" onclick="scrollHorizontally(-1)"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
                Card 1
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 2
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 3
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 4
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 5
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 1
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 2
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 3
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 4
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                Card 5
            </div>
        </div><!--card-container-->
    </div><!--horizontal-scroll-->
```

Comment: You are increasing the "left" style of your card container which is not absolutely positioned, so that has no effect at all. You could instead move it by setting a translateX transform. Also add a transition style for having it animated then.

Comment: is it a problem in css? There is no problem in javascript right? Can you tell exactly where should i add? i can grasp a little though.

Comment: i got you see i've made changes. i didn't get your translateX transform?

Comment: initially margin-left is there, but when i scroll there doesn't remain any gap? what should i do?

Comment: i'm ready to pay a small amount if you can calculate and tell me the offset width or maxScroll equivalent to stop it at max scroll.

Comment: No need to send any money. It's hard to just tell you "the fix" for your code as there are lots of issues. I've thrown something together real quick, maybe it helps or provides some inspiration: https://jsfiddle.net/3h2dLfxa/121/ 
The max index on line 36 (JS) is harcoded as are the styles. Obviously you'd want all things to be dynamically adjustable probably. In general I think you'd be better of using an existing slider library such as https://swiperjs.com.